# Change hover to click in Bootstrap menu

Tags: javascript, onclick, hover

I use Bootstrap data toggle drop down and data toggle hover to make a menu drop like a modal window. I want to change the hover and make it appear when you click.

I do not use JavaScript very often and would like to get help to change the code from hover to click. Here is the code:

```
    "use strict";
      /* Navigation */
      jQuery("#nav > li").hover(function()
      {
    var e = jQuery(this).find(".level0-wrapper");
    e.hide(), e.css("left", "0"), e.stop(true, true).delay(150).fadeIn(300, "easeOutCubic")
  }, function()
  {
    jQuery(this).find(".level0-wrapper").stop(true,   true).delay(300).fadeOut(300, "easeInCubic")
      });
      slideEffectAjax()
      jQuery("#nav li.level0.drop-menu").mouseover(function()
    {
      return jQuery(window).width() >= 740 &&    jQuery(this).children("ul.level1").fadeIn(100), !1
    }).mouseleave(function()
    {
      return jQuery(window).width() >= 740 && jQuery(this).children("ul.level1").fadeOut(100), !1
    }), jQuery("#nav li.level0.drop-menu li").mouseover(function()
    {
      if (jQuery(window).width() >= 740)
      {
        jQuery(this).children("ul").css(
        {
          top: 0,
       enter code here   left: "165px"
        });
        var e = jQuery(this).offset();
        e && jQuery(window).width() < e.left + 325 ? (jQuery(this).children("ul").removeClass("right-sub"), jQuery(this).children("ul").addClass("left-sub"), jQuery(this).children("ul").css(
        {
          top: 0,
          left: "-167px"
        })) : (jQuery(this).children("ul").removeClass("left-sub"),  jQuery(this).children("ul").addClass("right-sub")), jQuery(this).children("ul").fadeIn(100)
      }
    }).mouseleave(function()
    {
      jQuery(window).width() >= 740 && jQuery(this).children("ul").fadeOut(100)
    }),
    function deleteCartInCheckoutPage()
    {
        return jQuery(".checkout-cart-index").on("click", function (e)
      {
        return e.preventDefault(), confirm(confirm_content) ? void 0 : !1
      }), !1
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle.net? Can you explain better what you need?

Comment: I have a drop down menu that drops when you hover it, I want to change this and let the menu drop when you click on it... I was thinking someone could take a look at the code and tell me how to change the "hover" or "mouseover" to click or onclick.

Comment: Change hover to click. It's all

Comment: It worked. The answer was so easy I made it difficult. Thanks.